# Encrypted Date of birth is not being saved in database of sinatra/ rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sinatra, date

Here is my code:

patient_profile.rb

```
class PatientProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
  ............
  attr_encrypted :dob, key: Base64.decode64(SECRET_KEY)
  validates_presence_of :dob
end
```

db/migrate/20200618205840_patient_profiles.rb

```
class PatientProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_profiles do |t|
      t.string :encrypted_gender
      t.string :encrypted_gender_iv
      t.string :encrypted_address
      t.string :encrypted_address_iv
      .....................

      t.date :encrypted_dob
      t.date :encrypted_dob_iv
      t.integer :patient_id, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

patients_controller.rb

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  # POST /api/v1/signup
  post '/signup' do
  patient = Patient.new(params[:patient])
  patient.password = params[:patient][:password]
  patient.unique_code = SecureRandom.hex(6)
  patient.confirmation_token = (SecureRandom.random_number(9e4) + 1e4).to_i
  patient.confirmation_sent_at = Time.now
    if patient.save
      token = JsonWebToken.encode(patient_id: patient.id)
      send_email(patient,
             "Account Verification",
             "Your verification code is #{patient.confirmation_token}")
      response = { patient: patient_response(patient), token: token }
  [200, response.to_json]
  else
    halt 422, error_message(patient.errors.full_messages)
  end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => error
  halt 422, error_message(error.message)
end
```

In postman we can post date and it shows posted.
But in database dob field is null.

What's an issue with this?

Thanks in advance.

Here is log:

[image: Here is my log]

Comment: Could you also share the controller code and the content of your log file where the controller gets called?

Comment: @ClemensKofler I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
  t.date :encrypted_dob
  t.date :encrypted_dob_iv
```

to

```
  t.string :encrypted_dob
  t.string :encrypted_dob_iv
```

and it works fine and saves encrypted dob in a database.